# How to programmatically link aws lambda to aws gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ansible, aws-api-gateway

I creates lambda with ansible. Its ok, and i get ApiId

```
- name: Create API Gateway
  environment:
    AWS_PROFILE: "{{ aws_profile_name }}"
  community.aws.aws_api_gateway:
    state: present
    endpoint_type: REGIONAL
    stage: "{{ stage_name }}"
    swagger_file: "{{ temp_swagger_lambda.path }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
```

But also need to create relation to lambda (through the UI it is done like this. But how to do it through cli or ansible I could not find)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it’s one at a time, something like this should work.

```
aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id 1234123412 --resource-id a1b2c3 --http-method GET --type AWS --integration-http-method POST --uri 'arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:lambda:path//2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123412341234:function:function_name/invocations'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/put-integration.html